# Set Marker to Current Location in Android using Mapbox-sdk v8.6.1

Tags: mapbox, marker, android-gps, mapbox-android, currentlocation

I am using the updated sdk of **Mapbox**. But I couldn't add *marker* to *current position*. Moreover I don't have the *latitude* and *longitude* of current location. I am just using **locationComponent** to show the current position. 
It will be very helpful if anyone raise your helping hands.. **Thanks in advance**.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem, what you have tried, and what resources you have already used? ~https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-location-listening/ shows how to track the device location.

If that's too complicated or you don't need to constantly track location, you can do `Location lastKnownLocation = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().getLastKnownLocation();` once the `LocationComponent` is set up (https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/show-a-users-location/).

```
Location lastKnownLocation = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().getLastKnownLocation();

lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
```

Now that you have the coordinates, you can add a `SymbolLayer` or add the new coordinates to an existing `SymbolLayer`'s GeoJSON.

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/marker-symbol-layer/

How to update the `SymbolLayer` GeoJSON so that a new marker appears:

```
map.getStyle(new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
  @Override
  public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {

    featureList.add(Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(lastKnownLocation.getLongitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLatitude())));

    FeatureCollection newFeatureCollection = FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(featureList);

    GeoJsonSource source = style.getSourceAs("symbol-layer-source-id");
    if (source != null) {
      source.setGeoJson(newFeatureCollection);
    }


  }
});
```

Comment: thanks you so much. And sorry for replying that late. It was a great help.